# PCA - trace back principal component to a dimension

Tags: python, pca

I have very data with MANY dimensions (thousands) and have successfully performed a principal components analysis on it.
[image]

The output looks as shown above. My problem is that (as shown on axis X), one principal component accounts for all of the variance. I worry that it is masking all of the other principal components. Therefore, I want to figure out which dimension the principal component corresponds to, and then eliminate it from my data. Is there a way to work out which dimension it corresponds to?

If any code is necessary to aid understanding, it is this:

```
print(fdata.shape) 

# scale data
scaled_fdata = preprocessing.scale(fdata.T) 

# setting up PCA

pca = PCA()
pca.fit(scaled_fdata)
pca_data = pca.transform(scaled_fdata)

# scree plot to see how many pricipal components are needed to account for most variance

per_var = np.round(pca.explained_variance_ratio_* 100, decimals=1)
labels = ['PC' + str(x) for x in range(1, len(per_var)+1)]

# create scree plot diagram to see how many principal components should be used

plt.bar(x=range(1,len(per_var)+1), height=per_var, tick_label=labels)
plt.ylabel('Percentage of Explained Variance')
plt.xlabel('Principal Component')
plt.title('Scree Plot - Females')
plt.show()

#do the PCA plot

pca_df = pd.DataFrame(pca_data, columns=labels)

plt.scatter(pca_df.PC1, pca_df.PC2)
plt.title('My PCA Graph - Females')
plt.xlabel('PC1 - {0}%'.format(per_var[0]))
plt.ylabel('PC2 - {0}%'.format(per_var[1]))

for sample in pca_df.index:
    plt.annotate(sample, (pca_df.PC1.loc[sample], pca_df.PC2.loc[sample]))

plt.show()
plt.qt()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to worry about `masking all of the other principal components`, since it is the very reason to do the principal component. Normally when you do the PCA, the corresponding Eigen Value will be reported, which will be used to rank the importance of the PC's, aka, the PC's are ranked based on how much they can explain the variance, the first one explained the most variance, which "masking" other PC's. Then the second, the third, and so on. All you need to do is plotting the Cumulative Summation of the Explained Variance, and select the cutoff of how many PC's you want to use. For example, of the top 5 PC's can explain 99% of the variance, you only need those 5 PC's.

Read through this: https://towardsdatascience.com/an-approach-to-choosing-the-number-of-components-in-a-principal-component-analysis-pca-3b9f3d6e73fe

Answer (score 0):

The Principle Component Analysis using Varimax Rotation here's the solution
glad if it works for you!!!

```html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
df = pd.read_excel('excel path')
df.drop(['DISTRICT'],axis=1,inplace=True)
numCOl = df
numCorr = numCOl.corr()
print(numCorr.round(3))
from factor_analyzer.factor_analyzer import calculate_bartlett_sphericity
chi_square_value,p_value=calculate_bartlett_sphericity(df)
chi_square_value, p_value
#performing kaiser mayer test (KO test)
from factor_analyzer.factor_analyzer import calculate_kmo
kmo_all,kmo_model = calculate_kmo(df)
kmo_model

fa = FactorAnalyzer()
fa.fit(df)

ev,v = fa.get_eigenvalues()
print(ev)

# ploting the graph
plt.scatter(range(1,df.shape[1]+1),ev)
plt.plot(range(1,df.shape[1]+1),ev)
plt.title('Screen Plot')
plt.xlabel('Number of Factors')
plt.ylabel('Eigenvalue')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
fa = FactorAnalyzer(n_factors=4,method='principal',rotation='varimax') here`
fa.fit(df)
data_1 = pd.DataFrame(fa.loadings_,index=df.columns)
data_1.round(3)
```